# Direct Sum Division

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would appreciate any help proving the following:

If
$$ 
(\oplus_{\alpha\in I}\mathbb{Z}) / G \cong \mathbb{Z}
$$
Then must 
$$
G\cong \oplus_{\alpha\in (I-\{\beta\})}\mathbb{Z}
$$ 
for an arbitrary $\beta\in I$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\oplus_{\alpha\in I}\mathbb{Z}) / G \cong \mathbb{Z}$ shows that the short exact sequence $0\to G\to \oplus_{\alpha\in I}\mathbb{Z}\to(\oplus_{\alpha\in I}\mathbb{Z}) / G \to 0$ splits, so $G$ is free of rank $|I|-1$.

Comment: Thank you! This works for any $I$ (not only finite). You split $\oplus_{\alpha\in I}\mathbb{Z}$ into $G \oplus (\oplus_{\alpha\in I}\mathbb{Z}) / G$ which is by assumption $G \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ dividing both sides modulo $\mathbb{Z}$ I get the result.